# Is Returning A Random Value From Function A Side Effect?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I was working on some F# code and I was working on a function to return a random string from a set of strings. Let's say I had something like this:

```
open System

let a = [|"a";"b";"c";"d"|]

let rstring (arr:string[]) =
   let r = new Random()
   arr.[r.Next(0,3)]

let resultstring = rstring a;;
```

My question is this: My understanding of the notion of functional programming is that if a given function has the same input each time it should always return the same output. So in this particular case is returning a different string each time a "side effect"?  I'm just curious.

If this is a duplicate question, just point me to the original and I'll close this.  I'm not sure what search string I would use to find any questions related to this one.

---

EDIT: Thanks for all the information everyone. It seems that I conflated the concepts of referential transparency and the lack of side-effects. So, thanks all for setting me straight on the difference and thanks for your answers.

Comment: Always returning the same result for the same arguments actually means being pure, not side effect free (definitions for side effect were already posted).

Comment: When you start picking nits, then "side effects" are not an interesting concept in software.  Referential transparency and/or purity are the interesting/useful concepts, and random/non-determinate functions are not referentially transparent, and that's what matters.  So in a sense, the OP is asking the wrong question, or at least not an interesting/useful one.  The question as posed by the title picks nits about definitions.  The thing that matters for software is, if your function returns different values for the same inputs, then it opens you to a whole class of bugs.

Comment: @delnan - pure by definition requires the function to have no side effects.  Just because a function always returns the same results doesn't make it pure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

The only way that a function can return different values from the same input is via side effects.  Other people may claim otherwise, but they are wrong.

(You can claim that 'reading the system time' (which is clearly based on effects) is not an effect.  By this definition, it's not a side-effect.  But that definition is not useful, since the only reason people "care" about side-effects is because they affect referential transparency.  In other words, referential transparency is the only thing that matters, and this function is clearly not referentially transparent.)

Comment: Really -- what about a random number generator connected to hardware that monitors atomospheric noise.  Why would it necessarily need to change program state?

Comment: The state of the atmosphere is now part of the program state.  In a completely still air room, perhaps there is not changing of state, but now the air in the room is part of the computation being modeled by your computer program.

Comment: To expand on Brian's point, the state of the program is changing in that case, even if you are not explicitly changing it. (Thinking of it this way helped me, figured it might help others)

Answer (score 7):

"Side effect" means that some state is changed by the function, not that the return value differs.  In your case, the function is doing both - it is changing the state of the PRNG and return a different value.

Edit:

I'll also add that if a function always returns the same value for a given input it is called idempotent.  Also "side effect" includes functions that read from an external state.  For example:

```
int global = 0;
int function()
{
  return global;
}
```

has side effects.

Comment: "*if a function always returns the same value for a given input it is called idempotent*" -- I hate to be *that girl*, but what you have is the definition of *pure*, not *idempotent* which refers to a function `f` which satisfies the property `f(f(x)) == f(x)` for all x. `let abs x = if x < 0 then -x else x` is pure and idempotent since `abs(abs(x)) == abs(x)`. The function `let succ x = x + 1` is pure but not idempotent since `succ(succ(x)) != succ(x)`.

Comment: @Juliet - mathematically speaking that is correct.  In computer science I've heard the term "idempotent" to mean both `f(f(x))==f(x)` AND to mean "always returns the same value for a given input".  Perhaps the term is being used incorrectly.  Also, pure has a much stricter meaning - a function can always return the same value for a given input but also cause side effects, making it impure.

Comment: For C or C++, reading from `global` has no side effect unless `global` is of `volatile` type.

Answer (score 2):

It's ok for a function to be non-determinate.  That is not a side-effect.  A side-effect would be if it somehow changed the state of the program in addition to returning a value. I would say that both side-effects and non-determinism are ways that functions in functional programming differ from mathematical functions.

Comment: Well, it does change the RNG's state. Although that side effect alone doesn't affect purity (incorporating the non-pure random number in the result does).

Comment: @delnan -- don't confuse the example with the question. The question is does non-determinism equate to a side-effect. The fact that the example is both non-determinate and has a side-effect doesn't imply that non-determinism is a side-effect.

Comment: there are two questions being asked here.  The title question: "Is Returning A Random Value From Function A Side Effect?" has a specific answer of "Yes".  The more general question: "Is non-determinism a side effect?" has a different answer as you pointed out.  Although I can't think of an example of a non-deterministic function that doesn't have side effects.

Comment: @Niki - that's only true for this particular implementation.  I can easily conceive of a true random number generator that doesn't affect program state.  Not that it would be particularly useful to a general population.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to PRNGs.  Although I'm pretty sure that "side effect" includes reading something stateful (as apposed to modifying), so the act of reading a RNG would be considered a side effect.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring implementation details of the random generator(which in practice requires side effects, and in theory doesn't have to), then this function is side effect free but not pure.

Basically imagine the function call to be an oracle machine that returns random numbers based entirely on nothing. There is a proof somewhere that says you can't do this, but for the time being just imagine it to be so.

If you treat a PRNG function as this oracle machine that gives you a random number each time you ask for it, hen it is side-effect free and impure, and the function inherits that.

The type of side effect that doesn't violate referential transparency is sometimes referred to as a "soft side effect" sine it doesn't alter the behavior of the program(note:before you tell me that reading the time changes the behavior of the number generated, the specification of the function call says that the function returns a random number. Reading the time clock is an implementation detail of getting that specification to work. Changing the time clock(except under extremely degenerate circumstances) does not alter the fact that the function returns a psuedo random number, since the specification doesn't detail what that number is.

The classic example of a soft side effect is logging, since programs usually don't inspect their logs and alter behavior based on it.

If you wanted to do this in a functionally pure way you would have to implement a state monad.

http://fsharpcode.blogspot.com/2008/12/f-state-monad-type-state-state-state-of.html

Basically take that, make you state a random number generator and the 'a an int, and then your control flow will isolate the impurity to a single function and creates a hard order on the sequencing.

There is really no point to doing this in F#, as having impure functions doesn't really cause problems(having functions with side effects on the other hand, does).

Of course that monad is impure, but it isolates the impurity nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe your example would be considered a side effect.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)

Comment: `Random()` causes side effects so rstring causes side effects.

Comment: @Niki - that may be true in this specific case, but in general simply returning an indeterminate value is not in itself a side effect.

Comment: @Niki what are the side effects of Random()?

Comment: @Mike Cheel - `Random()` is seeded by the system time which is stateful, and `r.Next(0,3)` modifies the internals of `r`.

Comment: @Niki I think it needs to modify the state of something or be observable. Reading the system clock is not modifying the time and r is defined inside the function and so is not observable (private). According to the wiki: In computer science, a function or expression is said to have a side effect if, in addition to producing a value, it also modifies some state or has an observable interaction with calling functions or the outside world.

Comment: @Mike Cheel - The next sentence in that wiki article includes the example "For example, a function might...read data...".  It also claims that "A side effect free function is always idempotent."  If this function is side effect free (as you claim) then it should also be idempotent which it is clearly not.

Comment: @Mike Cheel - I would also consider rstring to have an "observable interaction" with the outside world when it reads from system time.  The fact that it produces different output depending on when it is called is observable.

Comment: @Nike I didn't claim that it was side effect free. I was just asking you questions about what you said.