# How to tell if an F# function is pure?

Tags: f#, pure-function

Suppose I have these two F# functions:

```
let sq x = x*x

let tm = DateTime.Now
```

Clearly sq is pure in that it will always return the same value for a given input while tm is impure because it will return a different value each time it is called.

In general is there a way to determine if a particular function in F# is pure or impure without analyzing what it does, in other words reading it line by line?

Alternatively is there a way to annotate a function to tell the compiler that the function is pure or impure when you write it?

Finally when calling a function that is part of the common language runtime (such as DateTime) how can one tell if it is pure or impure without trying it?

Note: by "pure" I mean the definition from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function ([permalink](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pure_function&oldid=586945449))

> In computer programming, a function may be described as pure if both
>   these statements about the function hold:
>
> 1. The function always evaluates the same result value given the same argument
>      value(s). The function result value cannot depend on any
>      hidden information or state that may change as program execution
>      proceeds or between different executions of the program, nor can it
>      depend on any external input from I/O devices.
> 2. Evaluation of the result does not cause any semantically observable side
>      effect or output, such as mutation of mutable objects
>      or output to I/O devices.

Comment: When you say pure, do you really mean idempotent?  Or do you mean that it causes no side effects?

Comment: Ah, so Wikipedia says both.  Fair enough. FWIW, I don't think Microsoft offers any sort of annotation or attribute that marks functions as "pure..." You just have to know.

Comment: You might also find the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391524/is-returning-a-random-value-from-function-a-side-effect worthwhile reading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

F# does not provide any features and tools for checking that methods are pure, so a simple answer is that you have to check this property yourself.

Outside of F#, it is worth noting that [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808.aspx) library has a notion of pure methods (and they can be marked with [`PureAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute.aspx)), but I'm not entirely sure what is the checking story there. I think Code Contracts come with static checker that analyses IL (and should work for F# too), but this is quite difficult task, so I would expect it to be quite limited. However, the `PureAttribute` is used on some BCL methods, so you can tell that some standard .NET methods are pure.

Comment: `PureAttribute` is just a way of telling Code Contracts that the function is pure - no analysis (runtime or static) is performed

Comment: Unfortunately, Code Contracts [still](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/11b8c5e3-a25d-4770-a46d-14f24921e0a0/f-and-code-contracts?forum=codecontracts) [doesn't](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7830b49c-ff45-4105-8609-1e2f8b81263d/when-will-f-be-supported?forum=codecontracts) work with F#.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking your 'tm' value is not a function, but value of type DateTime and it is immutable, so every time you evaluating this value after creating it will always be the same.

Comment: ...and to clarify even further, if you said 

let tm() = DateTime.Now 

(note added brackets) you would force it to be a function which was probably your intent.

Answer (score -1):

Given that it is possible to define both, pure and inpure functions in f#, I would be well surprised if there was an algorithm that can check f# code (function definitions) for purity -- checking program code for semantic properties is generally undecidable by Rice's theorem.

Comment: [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#procedures-func) and [Haxe](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-metadata.html) actually do that and both stand knee-deep in both imperative and functional programming, so it's possible.

Comment: Do they do that in some cases or all cases?

Comment: Nim added the last remaining edge case coverage a couple of weeks ago.
I dont know about Haxe.

Comment: The thread starter wants to be able "to determine if a particular function in F# is pure or impure". From what I understand, Nim verifies that some pure functions are in fact pure. However, I understand that the threadstarter wants a procedure, that given *any* function decides whether or not the function at hand is pure. In particular, If a function interacts with a global mutable variable *but finally does not change it*, this (depending on your definition of pureness) should be recognized as a pure function - which I still think is not possible.

Comment: Yeah, that could be true. Still, F# can do not one and not the other and the comment, that this is simply not possible in some language that supports imperative design, is incorrect.